# How to add to schema "\n" (PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory) using API?

Tags: json, xml, solr

I need remove all **\n**  in content. I decided use **PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory** and i need add to schema.xml

```
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="\n" replace="all" replacement=""/>
```

using API call. But, solr encode this pattern. 
I call

```
curl -X "POST" "http://localhost:$PORT/solr/$CORE_NAME/schema" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d $'{
  "add-field-type": {
   ........
    "indexAnalyzer": {
      "filters": [
        {
          "class": "solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory",
          "pattern":"\n",
          "replacement":"",
          "replace":"all"
        },]
        ...........
    }
```

but solr create in schema.xml

```
      <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="
 " replace="all" replacement=""/>
```

I tried add **\n , \n, (\n)** but result same, it not working.

Comment: Although the curl line is clear in terms of behaviour, it is unusable immediately, for example on a collection given with Solr as sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The escaped backslash did work for me: `"pattern": "\\n"`.

I've checked that in managed-schema file:

```
<fieldType name="myNewTextField" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory" delimiter="/"/>
    <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="\n" replace="all" replacement=""/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

So the full curl-command would look like:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' "http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/schema" -d '{
  "add-field-type": {
    "name": "myNewTextField",
    "class": "solr.TextField",
    "indexAnalyzer": {
      "tokenizer": {
        "class": "solr.PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory",
        "delimiter": "/"
      },
      "filters": [
        {
          "class": "solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory",
          "pattern": "\\n",
          "replacement": "",
          "replace": "all"
        }
      ]
    },
    "queryAnalyzer": {
      "tokenizer": {
        "class": "solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Thanks, I used **$** in a curl query before  `-d $'{  "add-field-type"`